# According to precedence Postfix increment has higher precendence than <= why i get Output as 5

Tags: c, operator-precedence

According to precedence Postfix increment has higher precendence than <= 
so when i run this program why do i get Output as 5?

[Example](http://cpp.sh/8jke)
Instead it Should execute as 

When a=1
  Check While condition 1++<=1
  Check While condition 2++<=2
  and then printf should print 3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    while(a++<=1)
    while(a++<=2);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you write such a terrible code ?

Comment: i'm new in C please bear me

Comment: The 'precedence' has no effect on the value or side-effect of `a++`. The value of `a++` is `a` at the previous sequence point (before any change), the side effect is increasing the value of `a` by `1`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with precedence and everything to do with what postfix actually does.

Comment: try to change **a++** with **++a** and you will get 2, or remove the **;** and see what you get :))

Comment: @Michi i tried replacing a++ with ++a and i get no output  http://cpp.sh/4dnjx

Comment: Congratulation :)) . It happens because you removed the semicolon from the second while :)). Put it back. Please read carefully again all my comments.

Comment: Thanks for explaining now i get output as 2 basically whats difference between while with semicolon and a while without it?

Comment: Yes, but where is exactly the big problem ? You should always use braces. check this: http://ideone.com/mXulwS

Comment: While with **;** is dangerous when condition is never met, you can find yourself into an Infinite loop. Try to avoid it. use braces with code inside which bring you out from that loop.

Comment: The indentation is misleading. I hope you're aware that the `while(a++<=2)` loop (which has an empty body) is nested within the `while(a++<=1)` loop. In any case, whatever this code is *intended* to do, there's certainly a clearer way to express that intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more to do with the semantics of the postfix `operator++` than precedence.

1) Check outer while condition `1++<=1`. The LHS evaluates to `1`, so we move into the inner `while`. `a` is incremented to `2`.

2) Check inner while condition `2++<=2`. The LHS evaluates to `2`, the condition is satisfied. `a` incremented to `3`.

3) Check inner while condition `3++<=2`. The LHS evaluates to `3`, the condition is not satisfied, `a` is incremented to `4`. We move back to the outer loop.

4) Check outer loop condition `4++ <= 1`. This fails, the loops end, and `a` is incremented to `5`.

Comment: thanks but if i remove semicolon from the inner while i Get the output as 3 why?

Comment: Because a++<= becomes 3  which is **> 2** and the loop terminates.

Comment: When you rich the second while a have the value of 2, second while increments the a(2) with 1 and becomes 3.

Comment: @CY5 If you remove the `;` in the inner while, that puts the `printf` inside the scope of the loops, so it doesn't see the increments due to the failed conditions.

Answer (score 1):

After so many comments I should  give you your expected Ouptut.

Try this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a=1;
    while(a++<=1){
        while(a++<=2){
            printf("%d",a);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Just because I use **BRACES**

EDIT:
I hope you know that A is still 5 when you are out of loops, ok ? but at least you can do something with a when a reach  3 inside that loop.

Comment: @cy5 You had right all the time, but you used your code wrong.
But this doesn't mean that the other's answers was wrong. You should know what and where you apply your code.

Comment: Please use BRACES in future or you will be remember me :))

Answer (score 0):

it is 5, because you add 1 in every cycle, even in the last cycle, when the condition is not true